# How can i get ubuntu to run smoother?

Tags: 10.10, animations

I am relatively new to ubuntu [I've used it before and loved it but one day i just randomly couldn't connect to the internet anymore so i switched back to windows... also netflix doesn't work in ubuntu...] and I've noticed that when i used it before everything ran very smoothly and the window animations and stuff like that were just beautiful. now though, everything is choppy and just ugly really. I wanna say its because i was using an older kernel but i really don't know.

Anyway, i guess my point is, How can i get it to look pretty again? i really do wish i could be more descriptive but... yeah...

I'm on Maverick btw. if anymore information is required i will happily oblige, just let me know.

I was told to post this... seems like a bit much and idk if it helps but here goes:

```
PCI (sysfs)  
knuckles-laptop           
    description: Computer
    width: 32 bits
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 1884MiB
     *-cpu
          product: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual-Core Processor TK-57
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 15.8.2
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch lbrv cpufreq
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 0
             size: 128KiB
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 1
             size: 256KiB
         *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: RS690 Host Bridge
          vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          configuration: latency=64
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (Internal gfx)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fe900000-feafffff ioport:e0000000(size=268435456)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series]
                vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
                physical id: 5
                bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=radeon latency=64
                resources: irq:19 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fe9f0000-fe9fffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fea00000-feafffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: Radeon X1200 Series Audio Controller
                vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
                physical id: 5.2
                bus info: pci@0000:01:05.2
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=64
                resources: irq:19 memory:fe9ec000-fe9effff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 1)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 memory:fe800000-fe8fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
                vendor: Broadcom Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
                logical name: eth1
                version: 01
                serial: 00:23:4e:36:6b:b9
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.60.48.36 ip=192.168.1.101 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:17 memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 2)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fe600000-fe7fffff ioport:f0000000(size=2097152)
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:22 ioport:6eb0(size=8) ioport:6eb8(size=4) ioport:6ec0(size=8) ioport:6ec8(size=4) ioport:6ee0(size=16) memory:80000000-800003ff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI0)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:ffb00000-ffb00fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI1)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 13.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:17 memory:ffb01000-ffb01fff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI2)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 13.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:ffb02000-ffb02fff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI3)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 13.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:17 memory:ffb03000-ffb03fff
        *-usb:4
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI4)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 13.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:ffb04000-ffb04fff
        *-usb:5
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 13.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.5
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:20 memory:ffa80000-ffa800ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: SBx00 SMBus Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 14
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: cap_list
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0 ioport:10c0(size=16)
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: SB600 IDE
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide bus_master emulated
             configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=64
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:bfa0(size=16)
           *-cdrom
                description: DVD-RAM writer
                product: DVD+-RW TS-L632H
                vendor: TSSTcorp
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/cdrw
                logical name: /dev/dvd
                logical name: /dev/dvdrw
                logical name: /dev/scd0
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: D400
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:febfc000-febfffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master
             resources: ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:fe500000-fe5fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 7
                bus info: pci@0000:03:07.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 10
                serial: 00:23:ae:03:37:c5
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 latency=64 maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes
                resources: irq:20 ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:fe5ff300-fe5ff3ff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 9
                bus info: pci@0000:03:09.0
                version: 05
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=64 maxlatency=4 mingnt=2
                resources: irq:23 memory:fe5ff800-fe5fffff
           *-generic:0
                description: SD Host controller
                product: R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 9.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:09.1
                version: 22
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=64
                resources: irq:22 memory:fe5ff400-fe5ff4ff
           *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
                description: System peripheral
                product: R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 9.2
                bus info: pci@0000:03:09.2
                version: 12
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=64
                resources: memory:fe5ff600-fe5ff6ff
           *-generic:2
                description: System peripheral
                product: xD-Picture Card Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 9.3
                bus info: pci@0000:03:09.3
                version: 12
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=r852 latency=64
                resources: irq:22 memory:fe5ff700-fe5ff7ff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k8temp
          resources: irq:0
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@4
       logical name: scsi4
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
```

Comment: If you have a good PC, try [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org/); else [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

Comment: Install proprietary drivers for your graphics card?

Comment: Upgrade ye old Pentium4? ;), what are the specs of your pc? , did you update anything before this started to happen?

Comment: @Uri, funny you mentioned Pentium IV, just what I am using. With Nvidia FX 5500 and proprietary driver installed, Unity doesn't work but the rest of the animations in Classic works just fine.

Comment: If you don't plan on doing any serious 3D stuff, you can use the open source drivers, nouveau.

Comment: i'm using my laptop and it has ATI radeon graphics... i'd be more specific but idk how to check that stuff in ubuntu and i can't switch to win 7 right now...

Comment: Knuckles install hardinfo (system profiler and benchmark) (from software center) or run lshw > output.txt in a terminal. Then post the output of either one here.

Comment: @roland ok i did hardinfo and it gave me ALOT of text, should i just copy and paste all of it or is there something in particular i'm looking for?

Comment: @Knuckles adding all is fine, we can scan through to find what might be useful.

Comment: @roland i put it in the question...

Comment: @Knuckles................ I'm aware of that.............. :)

Comment: @roland lol, sorry...

Comment: @Takkat how do i install proprietary drivers?... also what does that mean?

Comment: @Knuckles: you can't sorry - for the ATI X1200 you **must** run the open source radeon driver you already have. Proprietary driver from ATI does not support you graphics card any more - blame ATI. On your hardware you may find that Lubuntu will run smoother

Comment: @takkat bummer... i can run everything fine if no animations are on, but that's just no fun...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, for pointing out the obvious, but have you installed the vendor's drivers for your graphic card?

You can check under `System -> Administration -> Additional Drivers`, if proprietary drivers are available.

Comment: feel free to point out the obvious, there's probably something very obvious that i am missing, lol.
but there aren't any other drivers showing up besides the ones for my wireless card...